# Echosign APIs and pre-populating text in a PDF

Tags: ruby, api, pdf, pdf-generation, echosign

I have a pdf with several text fields. I have used Echosign's tutorial on creating text tags to create the tags but the Echosign API expert told me that the API method I've been told to use (createURLWidget) does not allow data to be prefilled using the prefill suffix.

I am using Ruby to run the methods.

my field name is full_name and I switched the actual document key with a fake one.

```
params = 
{
  :name => 'Agreement',
  :document_key => '3434hkfhegeg',
  :mime_type => 'application/pdf',
  :fields => 
  {
    :full_name => 'Mary'
  }
}
```

the text tags that I've tried are:

```
full_name_es_:sender:fullname
full_name_es_:signer
full_name_es_:signer1
full_name_es_:signer2
full_name_es_:sender
```

Here's the naming syntax:

```
<field_name>_es_<:Role><:Field Type>
```

I've tried them Read-only and not.

When I run "ruby create_url_widget.rb" in terminal

This is the relevant part of my response:

```
<mergeFieldInfo><ns9:MergeFields/><ns9:fieldName>full_name</ns9:fieldName>
<ns9:defaultValue>Mary</ns9:defaultValue></ns9:MergeFields></mergeFieldInfo>
```

a URL is also generated with the correct PDF embedded in the page on echosign's site. However, no text has been places where the full_name field is located. If I have made that text "read-only," it's no longer a box to fill-in, if I make it required, the box is red-outlined and when I have a date text tag that I test, it fills it in appropriately so I know it's doing something.

I have used soupUI to try to change up my code with still no luck.

If anyone needs more code from me, let me know. If anyone has any suggestions, let me know, I am really stuck. I don't even know for sure if this API method will do this for sure, does anyone know this or should I be using another method?

Thank you for your time in advance!

Comment: Hi there. What is the `prefill` suffix you mentioned in your question introduction? I'm trying to find some info on it but failing so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! I needed to add a MergeField parameter in addition to the pre-existing mergeFieldInfo and mergeFields. Since each text field needed it's own MergeField parameter, it had to be placed within the each_pair do loop.

code in my xml builder:

```
if has?( :fields, Hash )
  xml.mergeFieldInfo do
     xml.tag! 'ns9:mergeFields' do
       fields.each_pair do | key, value |
         xml.tag! 'ns9:MergeField' do 
           xml.tag! 'ns9:fieldName', key.to_s
           xml.tag! 'ns9:defaultValue', value.to_s
         end
       end
     end
  end
end
```

working text tag example:

```
full_name_es_:signer1
```

what my response looks like:

```
<mergeFieldInfo><ns9:mergeFields>
<ns9:MergeField><ns9:defaultValue>Kristoph</ns9:defaultValue><ns9:fieldName>full_name</ns9:fieldName></ns9:MergeField>
<ns9:MergeField><ns9:defaultValue>123 Mockingbird Lane</ns9:defaultValue><ns9:fieldName>address_1</ns9:fieldName></ns9:MergeField>
</ns9:mergeFields></mergeFieldInfo>
```

Answer (score 0):

prefill tags are supposed to be used when sender is required to provide certain data before sending the document for signature. You can test this by using a prefill tag (e.g. full_name_es:prefill) to your document, make sure "Preview, position signatures or add form fields" option is selected when sending the document to the recipient for esignatures. In the preview position screen you can also provide default values to the (tag) fields that you have placed in the document.
*es*:signer[#]:fullname should capture the fullname of the signer when the document is sent out for signatures using sendDocument method (full_name_es_:sender:fullname is not a valid text tag and will not work). It seems that you are trying to create a generic widget that you could reuse to capture signatures from different signers. Generic widgets behave differently since you dont know the signers beforehand (createURLWidget does not take recipeint email) so it will not prefill the signers name. You should consider using a different widget generation method (createPersonalUrlWidget) if you want to generate this widget for specific signer.
I do not know ruby so I cannot promise any help with your ruby code but I can give it a shot if you can provide me with your source code and document.

Comment: Please do not include your email address in your answer.  It does not benefit the community at large if solutions are not posted here.

Comment: I'm not looking to prefill the pdf while signed into the echosign site. As I said in my OP, I was told by echosign not to use prefill with createUrlWidget. I did try your suggestion of using createPersonalUrlWidget with no luck. I am using Ruby code to add the prefilled values to the pdf and upload pdf to echosign server. The only part not working is the prefilled data on the pdf does not happen. Thanks for your suggestions.